# Подключение к базе данных Postgres из Docker контейнера

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Моя задача была написать скрипт, получающий информацию с удаленного компьютера и записывающий полученную информацию на локально расположенной Postgres DataBase. Тесты прошли успешно. Данные приходили, база данных обновлялась.

Следующим этапом стало размещение данного скрипта в докер контейнере. Dockerfile и Docker-Compose.yml прилагаю ниже. Окружение с рабочими программами добавляю в контейнер через Volume. Docker контейнер работает на локальной машине, где расположена postgres data base.
При запуске образа контролирую рабочий процесс программы и наблюдаю получение данных с удаленного компьютера, но запись сообщений в postgres data base  по адресу - `postgres+psycopg2://postgres:hi123@localhost:5432/Back` не происходит.

Каким образом можно разрешить проблему с подключением docker контейнера  к локально расположенной базе данных?

```
=---------Dockerfile---------=
FROM python:latest
WORKDIR /backend
COPY requirements.txt /backend/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
=----------------------------=

=-----Docker-compose.yml-----=
    version: '3'

    services:
      back:
        image: git_rep_2_back:latest
        environment:
          - PYTHONPATH=/backend/
        volumes:
          - "./Platform:/backend"
        command: bash -c "cd server && python launcher.py"
=-----------------------------=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker не способ подключения к базе, а средство упаковки.

Если база находится в той же подсети что и контейнер, убедитесь, что:

добавлено разрешение на подключение в

*/etc/postgresql/*/main/pg_hba.conf*

```
...
host    all             all             ВАША_ПОДСЕТЬ/24            md5
...
```

PostgreSQL "вещает" на все IP

*/etc/postgresql/*/main/postgresql.conf*

```
...
listen_addresses = 'localhost,IP_ВАШЕЙ_ПОДСЕТИ'               # what IP address(es) to listen on;
...
```